# Second moment SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, covariance, variance

Let $W_t$ be a standard Wiener process.
Is there a general closed formula for the second moment of the SDE:
$$
dX_t= A (X) \; dt + \sigma \; dW_t 
$$
$\sigma $  constant and $A(X)$ smooth in $X$?

Comment: in general not. smoothness does not make the derivations easy so that a closed form be available.

Comment: Depends on $A$. For instance, the [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) does, which is a special case of your process.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the formula of the OU process and this inspired my question.

Comment: In full generality, $$\frac{d}{dt}E(X_t)=E(A(X_t))\qquad\frac{d}{dt}E(X_t^2)=\sigma^2+2E(X_tA(X_t))$$ but except for some specific functions $A$ there is no hope to get explicit formulas (already for the derivative of the *first* moment).

Comment: Can we say in this case $$  \frac{d}{dt} V =\sigma^2+2 \sqrt{V}   A( \sqrt{V}) \quad  V:= E(X_t^2)$$